# How to open a document located at remote server from web root of another server in PHP?

Tags: php

cdsapplication is folder name inside htdocs.

```
localhost/cdsapplication/itemslist.php?showmaster=Product_list&PARENT_ID=2
```

This PHP page contains a link like this

```
<a href="\\srv01\CDS\ITEMS\ITEMLIST.xls" target="_blank">document</a>
```

ITEMLIST.xls document is available at srv01 server(srv01 and localhost are two different servers).
When I click on document link the url becomes like this

```
http://localhost/cdsapplication/\\srv01\CDS\ITEMS\ITEMLIST.xls
```

But requirement is, when user clicks document link the url should be

```
\\srv01\CDS\ITEMS\ITEMLIST.xls
```

I mean open remote server document location from web root of another php server.

Comment: Sounds like you want to use the [`file:// `](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme) protocol

Comment: Are you trying to Open xls on your windows machine? It will work with IE only. Anyway, the link should contain file:// at the beginning to block 'assumption' that the file is the local one.

Comment: you can access it directly via `http://srv01/CDS/ITEMS/ITEMLIST.xls`

Comment: @SumitBijvani: not if that srv01 has a web server!

Comment: @MatteoTassinari I think another server is localhost, so `http://` protocol will work

Comment: @SumitBijvani: it could be a local server, but if it has a web server installed, listening on port 80, then the web server would answer instead.

Comment: I cannot access like this, http://srv01/CDS/ITEMS/ITEMLIST.xls  . Link should redirect to \\srv01\CDS\ITEMS\ITEMLIST.xls

Answer (score 0):

You should use file-urls.

```
<a href="file://srv01/CDS/ITEMS/ITEMLIST.xls" target="_blank">document</a>
```